# c# xml how DeSerializer Model

Tags: c#, xml

```
string xmlstr = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>"
              + "<SampleModel>"
              + "<FIELD name=\"ID\">9693</FIELD>"
              + "<FIELD name=\"PARAM_NAME\">93223335</FIELD>"
              + "<FIELD name=\"DATA_TYPE\">1</FIELD>"
              + "<FIELD name=\"CREATE_DATE\">2017/2/22 14:43:20</FIELD>"
              + "<FIELD name=\"UPDATE_DATE\">2017/2/22 14:43:20</FIELD>"                 
              + "</SampleModel>";

[Serializable]
[XmlRootAttribute("SampleModel")]
public class SampleModel
{
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public string PARAM_NAME { get; set; }

    public string DATA_TYPE { get; set; }

    public string CREATE_DATE { get; set; }

    public string UPDATE_DATE { get; set; }
}

public static object Deserialize (Type, type, string, XML)
{
    try
    {
        using (StringReader Sr = new StringReader(XML))
        {
            XmlSerializer xmldes = new XmlSerializer (type);
            return xmldes.Deserialize(SR);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       return null;
    }
 }
```

I want to make the XML Deserialize object,
This method fails. Do you want to add property [XmlElement ('FIELD') when defining properties?
I don't know how to define the class structure. Can you help me?

Comment: Please **--> [edit] <--** your question and include the error message you get. I fixed various capitalization errors in your code - if this represented your actual code you should fix those first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML and your object aren't really the same. There are only repeated elements called `FIELD`, there are no elements with the names you've created properties for.

You need an object structure that mirrors the XML:

```
public class SampleModel
{
    [XmlElement("FIELD")]
    public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```